# Inner join "not unique table"

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a procedure using inner joins. I keep getting following error:

```
Not unique table/alias: 'car'
```

What am i doing wrong?

My procedure

```
DELIMITER //   
CREATE PROCEDURE orderCreate(IN _LicenseNumber varchar(30), _Phonenumber varchar(20))
BEGIN    
INSERT INTO `order` (carID, clientID) 
Select car.id, client.id 
FROM car, client, owns   
INNER JOIN car 
ON car.id = owns.carID

INNER JOIN owns 
ON owns.clientID = client.id;

WHERE  car.licensenumber = _LicenseNumber 
AND client.phonenumber = _Phonenumber 
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); 

END // 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: If you're going to join onto the same table more than once you need to specify an alias to at least one of the copies of the table so SQL knows which copy of the table you mean when you say `car.id`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing both an `INNER JOIN` and a cartesian product (which is the same in MySQL<sup>1</sup>):

```
FROM car, client, owns   
INNER JOIN car 
ON car.id = owns.carID

INNER JOIN owns 
ON owns.clientID = client.id;
```

Just remove `car` and `owns` from your `FROM` statement.

If you want both, you have to add an alias to `car` and `owns`:

```
FROM car AS car1, clients, owns AS owns1
```

#### References

1. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/join.html

> INNER JOIN and , (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of
>   a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product between the
>   specified tables

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to many tables:
Try:

```
INSERT INTO `order` (carID, clientID) 
Select car.id, client.id 
FROM car    
INNER JOIN owns 
ON owns.clientID = client.id;
WHERE  car.licensenumber = _LicenseNumber 
AND client.phonenumber = _Phonenumber 
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: You are missing an join operation.

Comment: okay would it in this case make sense to joins or should i just stick to WHERE clauses?

Comment: @user3660361 it is up to you. I prefer `join`.